# Jquery hide a div when a radio button checked resetting to show when IE browser refreshes

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a Div when a radio button is checked using jquery. My Jquery code works on page Load, but when the user refreshes the IE browser, then the hide is changed to show. Below is my code and any help will be appreciated.

```js
$("[name='Radios']").click(function () {
 if ($("input:radio.Radio base:checked")) {
  $("#EmployeeSelection").hide();
 }
});
```

```html
<label type="radio" value="2" name="Radios">
 <input name="RadioButton" class="Radio base" id="checkbox" type="radio">
</label>

 <div id="EmployeeSelection">
            <div>
                <h4>
                    <span>Documents</span>
                </h4>                 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when the user refreshes the IE browser, then the hide is changed to show

This issue is not only related to IE but is a common result you have whenever you refresh the browser. All you need is to save necessary data on server side or client side between pages or refreshes. 
On client side you may use [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) and a jQuery plugin or a plain JS code in order to save the state of your **Radios** element.
Instead of the **click** event you may consider to use the **change** event for your radio button.

```js
$("[name='Radios']").on('change', function (e) {
    if ($(this).children().is(":checked")) {
        //
        // set cookie on change
        //
        Cookies.set('Radios', true, { expires: 1 });
        $("#EmployeeSelection").hide();
    }
});

//
// test cookie at page load
//
var rCookie = JSON.parse(Cookies.get('Radios') || false);
if (rCookie) {
    $("[name='Radios']").trigger('click');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>


<label type="radio" value="2" name="Radios">
    <input name="RadioButton" class="Radio base" id="checkbox" type="radio">
</label>


<div id="EmployeeSelection">
    <div>
        <h4>
            <span>Documents</span>
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried all the suggested solutions above and none of them works. When I refresh the browser hide change to Show

Comment: the snippet doesn't work due to sandbox issue. If you copied libs and code It works

Answer (score 0):

Create a function instead an run it on refresh:

```
// Create function 
function hideSelection() {
    if ($("input:radio.Radio base:checked")) {
        $("#EmployeeSelection").hide();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Action on click 
    $(document).on('click', '[name="Radios"]', function () {
        hideSelection(); 
    });

    // Action on refresh 
    hideSelection(); 
});
```

Comment: BTW: Internet Explorer is dying.